# Java ini4j error reading file created by windows software

Tags: java, netbeans, ini4j

I am trying to use the ini4j to get data from a windows software log file. The file looks like:

```
[Production]
Code=I-MS01-11002
Time=2012-01-25T15:58:50+02:00
RequestType=Process Order
OrderID=0183
```

When I try:

```
Wini ini = new Wini(fileList[i]);
System.out.println(ini.keySet());
```

The output is: [?, P  r  o  d  u  c  t  i  o  n]

Please advise where I am going wrong.

Comment: The problem is something to do with the way the file is saved. If I open the file in a text editor, copy all the contents, and paste it in a new file, the code above works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the original file is saved in UTF16 format. A work around, that seems to work, but may not be the best way to do it:

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileList[i]));
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-16");
Ini ini = new Ini();
ini.load(reader);
System.out.println(ini.keySet());
```

The output is now: [Production]